# Salesforce export to Excel template

Tags: excel, automation, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am new to Salesforce and don't know where to start for this task. I have a fairly complex macro enabled template that I would like to populate with record field data from Lead objects via a button on the individual record and save on my local machine. I have been searching for ways tackle this problem, but I haven't found any examples quite like it. How would you recommend I do this?

I can find ways to export to CSV via quick action button: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/367727/download-a-csv-file-from-a-lightning-component-using-a-button

or pushing individual record data to external DB:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/360431/how-to-push-individual-record-data-to-external-db-via-quick-action-button-via-lw

;however, I cannot find anything related to using a pre-existing template. Ideally I would like to make this work with a button within Salesforce. If needed, I can simplify to just download to a CSV and import that data manually (or by VBA); but, where is the fun in that?

Thanks,
Charlie

Comment: Consider asking on dedicated salesforce.stackexchange.com. it's possible there's a code-free solution but you'd have to pay.

Answer (score 0):

Read up Salesforce documentation around mail merge and extended mail merge. If they don't do what you need - you probably could pull off something custom and fragile with JavaScript libraries that can manipulate excel and try to populate your template that way.

There are few companies on appexchange with their own "merge" solutions. Conga is/was a big name, I had some good experience with webmerge (renamed to formstack now I think) (I'm not affiliated with either). Just read carefully what exactly they do, it's possible your data travels from Salesforce to some C# or PHP service where it's easier to manipulate MS Office documents. You may have legal limitations that prevent you from sending data say from Europe to US East Coast...